# Open application when click on notification in electron.js app

Tags: notifications, electron, webrtc

I created one Electron application using webRTC where I implemented the notification for incoming call. When I click on notification I need that my application should be open if it is minimize.

Could anyone suggest me the way?

```js
function showNotification (body_content) {
  let myNotification = new Notification({ title: NOTIFICATION_TITLE, 
    body: `Incoming Call from ${body_content}` }).show()

  console.log(myNotification,'notification')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the browser window variable as global and display it with the show() function when you click the notification.

```
var browserWindow = null;

function createWindow () {
  browserWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600
  })

  browserWindow.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

function showNotification (body_content) {
  let myNotification = new Notification({ title: NOTIFICATION_TITLE, 
    body: `Incoming Call from ${body_content}` })

  console.log(myNotification,'notification')
  myNotification.show()
  myNotification.on('click', (event, arg)=>{
    console.log("notification clicked")
    browserWindow.show()
  })
}
```